# Force to the conductor with current in the permanent homogeneous magnetic field

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

What they tell total force for the circuit with current will be zero in the permanent homogeneous magnetic field. I understand, that circuit always should be closed (in a kind of loop) and on the one side of the circuit will be one force, on another side force will be in a different direction which gives zero in total.

But what if half of the circuit we will cover by magnetic shield like described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_shielding#Magnetic_shielding)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you place a "mu-metal" shield around part of the circuit, then the magnetic field won't be homogeneous in that region, and the net force will not necessarily be zero.